Azure App Service communicating with another App service deployed in a different region
I am doing a test project on azure. I have 4 app services deployed. All in different regions, all free tier.
One of the deployed app services was supposed to be a gateway that would communicate with all the other services.
I ran the code for my gateway locally, but kept the deployed urls for other app services, and everything worked fine.
After I deployed the gateway though, I would always get 502 bad gateway errors.
What could be the issue here?

Are you using free subscription? can you share your exact error?

I had a setup with FastEndpoints that looked like this:
 public class GetFlashCardEndpoint : Endpoint<EntityRequest, Response<FlashCardResponse>>
 {
     public IOptionsMonitor<GatewayOptions> OptionsMonitor { get; set; }
     public HttpClientService HttpClientService { get; set; }
     public override void Configure()
     {
         Get("/flash-cards/{Id}");
         Summary(s =>
         {
             s.Summary = "Returns a specific flashcard";
             s.Description = "This endpoint retrieves a flashcard by its ID for a specified user ID.";
             s.Params["Id"] = "The unique identifier of the flash card";
         });
     }
     public override async Task HandleAsync(EntityRequest request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
     {
         var url = $"{OptionsMonitor.CurrentValue.FlashCardsHost}/flash-cards/{request.EntityId}";

         await HttpClientService.SendRequestAsync(url, cancellationToken);
     }

public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendRequestAsync(string url, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{

    var method = new HttpMethod(_context.Request.Method);
    var requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(method, url);
    Log.Information("HttpClientService reached SendRequestAsync.");
    AddHeaders(requestMessage);
    if (_context.Request.ContentLength > 0 && (method == HttpMethod.Post || method == HttpMethod.Put || method == HttpMethod.Patch || method == HttpMethod.Delete))
    {
        var requestBody = await _context.Request.GetRawBodyAsync();
        requestMessage.Content = new StringContent(requestBody, Encoding.UTF8, _context.Request.ContentType);
    }
    HttpResponseMessage response = await _httpClient.SendAsync(requestMessage, cancellationToken);
    await StreamResponseBackToClient(response, cancellationToken);
    return response;
}

private async Task StreamResponseBackToClient(HttpResponseMessage response, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    _context.Response.StatusCode = (int)response.StatusCode;
    foreach (var header in response.Headers)
    {
        _context.Response.Headers[header.Key] = header.Value.ToArray();
    }
    foreach (var contentHeader in response.Content.Headers)
    {
        _context.Response.Headers[contentHeader.Key] = contentHeader.Value.ToArray();
    }

    if (response.Content != null)
    {
        await response.Content.CopyToAsync(_context.Response.Body, cancellationToken);
    }
}

I want to highlight that this setup was fully functional when running locally.
After calling an endpoint on the deployed gateway application, the logs would show that I successfully communicated with the other services, but the gateway would "spin" for a much longer time, even though the service it was communicating with returned a response.
I suspect the 502 bad gateway was being thrown due to a timeout, since if you will look at the endpoint logic I do not send back a response, instead my scoped httclient service would modify the http context directly as seen in the StreamResponseBackToClient, which for a reason I didn't manage to understand works locally but doesn't in the cloud.
When I posted the question, I thought my request couldn't reach the other services, because they were deployed in different regions. I was informed that is not the case, and without the need for any additional configuration, the apps should have no problems communicating, which I then confirmed after inspecting the logs.
In the end I couldn't figure out the issue and just switched to using .net Ocelot, which worked.
